# Putting a searchbar/button/ANYTHING on top of a google maps view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.delegate = self
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
view = mapView
    search.delegate = self
    view.insertSubview(searchbar, aboveSubview: view)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: searchbar)// view that UISearchBar is in
    view.bringSubview(toFront: search) // actual searchBar
```

I have tried all kinds of things to make the `searchBar` show up. The mapView isn't connected to the CityViewController in the storyboard, just here programmatically for the CityViewController.The storyboard just has a View with the SearchBar located inside of it. The google Maps loads fine in the program but the searchBar NEVER shows up when the program runs but is on the storyboard. If I add the mapView as a subView as well, mapView doesn't show up anymore.

EDIT: I have placed the search bar into a UI View into the main view of the ViewController. If I add constraints, the search bar does not appear. However, it does if I do this. However, I can not type inside of the search bar. I have editted the code to show this.

Comment: 1. Check constraints of search bar. 
2. The search bar should be under your map view in view heirarchy
[https://ibb.co/hfpSMJ]

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz If I choose 'add missing constraints', even with my new method above ( I editted the original post ) , all of it disappears again. However, I still cant type in the search bar. When you say 'under my map view' do you mean within the map view? So, indented and under map view? The map view isn't actually in story board. It has just been added in programmatically and then view = mapView. See above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. Drag and drop a search bar on your view controller. set its leading, trailing, and top to 0. Set a constant height of 50.

Then, drag and drop UIView for google maps view. set its class to GMSMapView in Class Inspector. See the screen shot.

[image: UIView]

Comment: Happy coding :)